# getting this error while building Android ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk

```
jni/../external/libjpeg/jidctfst.S: Assembler messages:
jni/../external/libjpeg/jidctfst.S:66: Error: missing ')'
jni/../external/libjpeg/jidctfst.S:66: Error: garbage following instruction -- 'pld (r2,#0)'
jni/../external/libjpeg/jidctfst.S:259: Error: missing ')'
jni/../external/libjpeg/jidctfst.S:259: Error: garbage following instruction -- 'pld (sp,#32)'
jni/../external/libjpeg/jidctfst.S:271: Error: missing ')'
jni/../external/libjpeg/jidctfst.S:271: Error: garbage following instruction -- 'pld (ip,#32)'
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/jpeg/jidctfst.o] Error 1
```

can anyone help me with this to resolve this error msg?

Comment: Can you enclose the code snippet that is throwing up the error as above?

Comment: here is the full code
http://tny.cz/86523ebf
actually i am building andriod ocr

Comment: OP: Please! The actual code, not the output of compilation and do not hotlinky to another site....

Comment: there is no single file? there are multi files

Answer (score 9):

Try changing the the parenthesis following the PLD instruction to brackets. That is, change

```
PLD (xx xx)
```

to

```
PLD [xx xx]
```

Comment: fixed the issue in my case

Answer (score 2):

Uncomment the ANDROID_JPEG_NO_ASSEMBLER line of the Android.mk, it is like that:

```
# temp fix until we understand why this broke cnn.com
#ANDROID_JPEG_NO_ASSEMBLER := true
```

do that:

```
# temp fix until we understand why this broke cnn.com
ANDROID_JPEG_NO_ASSEMBLER := true
```

Answer (score 1):

trying to compile Android on Windows with Cygwin it's a pain. 
Follow the guides on XDA-Developers.com to compile android under Ubuntu Linux, its easy as in a Windows Cygwin Environment and it works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

i have the same error and some solutions says change PLD from UPPERCASE to lowercase 
e.g. from `"PLD"` to `"pld"` .